# How to get list when running total crosses a set limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, report, cumulative-sum

I have a mysql table with `ID`, `UniqName`,`Category`, `EntDate`, `Qty`.

I have to find the `EntDate` for each `UniqName` when the sum of `Qty` in a 'Category' goes beyond a set limit.

I am a beginner in SQL and am stumped by this report requirement.

Comment: `SELECT UniqName, EntDate, SUM(EntDate) FROM ... GROUP BY UniqName` produces roughly the right data, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating a running sum can be complex.  Some databases offer direct support.  Here is a method in MySQL using correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.qty)
              from t t2
              where t2.UniqName = t.UniqName and
                    t2.EntDate <= t.EntDate
             ) as cumsum
      from t
     ) t
where cumsum >= YOURLIMIT and cumsum - qty < YOURLIMIT;
```

This can even have reasonable performance, if you have an index on `t(UniqName, EntDate, qty)`.

This query assumes that `EntDate` is not duplicated for each `UniqName` and that `qty` is not NULL.  If `qty` can be zero or negative, you might get multiple rows.

Comment: I have over 400,000 rows in the table .. and yes EntDate is not duplicated for each UniqName and qty is not null. I tried running this.. but it went 'not responding'.

Comment: @jagzviruz . . . Try doing this with an index (very important for 400,000 rows).  There is an alternative way to write this using MySQL variables, but I don't have the time now to do it.